# bat script working on windows 7 but not on windos 2k8

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a script which works on windows 7 but not on 2k8 throwing up an exception of file not found.

```
@echo off
REM #Testing FIND in IPCONFIG
SET VIPTHATWORKS="11.11.11.11"
SET VIPTHATFAILS="192.168.122.17"

ipconfig /all | find %VIPTHATWORKS%
if ERRORLEVEL = 1 goto VIP_NOT_FOUND

REM #We are here becuase the find returned a result.
REM #It is safe to execute the rest of the application.
REM #EXECUTES THE SCRIPT HERE

echo "testing works" >> testing.txt

:VIP_NOT_FOUND
REM #This part of the script is where you would handle any
REM #error logging or other admin related
echo "Could not find a VIP. - Exiting"
echo "end of script reached."
```

Comment: This is just a hunch, maybe `IPCONFIG` information is read from a file in win7, which on 2k8 is missing. Otherwise, I can't see where else your script might access a file.

Answer (score 0):

What name did you call your batch file?

Below are a couple of things to note:

if ERRORLEVEL = 1 goto VIP_NOT_FOUND

The above is not quite as it should be - one way to do it is below:

```
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto VIP_NOT_FOUND
```

This line below requires a goto :EOF as shown.

```
echo "testing works" >> testing.txt
goto :EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

It is to change from this

```
ipconfig /all | find %VIPTHATWORKS%
if ERRORLEVEL = 1 goto VIP_NOT_FOUND
```

to this

```
ipconfig /all | findstr %VIPTHATWORKS%
if ERRORLEVEL = 1 goto VIP_NOT_FOUND
```